# does strrchr return nullptr instead of NULL in C++?

Tags: c++, c

I'm porting the program from C to C++ including this code:

```
char* get_file_extension(const char* file_name)
{
    char* e = strrchr((char*) file_name, '.');
    if (e == NULL)
    {
        char* buf = strdup(file_name);
        return buf;
    }
    return e + 1;
}
```

Assuming that I'm only changing compiler to c++11, is it enough to just change **NULL** to **nullptr** in this case? Currently strrchr is from included header **string.h**, so I'm afraid if strrchr return **NULL** instead of **nullptr** and if(e == **nullptr**) check fail.

Or should I change **string.h** to **cstring**?

Comment: Why the cast in the call to `strrchr` ?

Comment: How is the memory for `file_name` being allocated because `strdup` uses `malloc`?

Comment: @PaulR - There are two `strrchr` overloads in the C++ version of the standard library. One for const pointers and one for non-const pointers. The cast may be to get the desired one. And the C version is a disgrace as far as const correctness goes.

Comment: This function just looks very dangerous to me. It is a confusing mix of const/non-const, owned/non-owned pointers. I don't even understand what it does. If the string has a `'.'` it returns a substring pointer otherwise it duplicates the entire string??

Comment: Fwiw, I suspect you want something more along the lines of: `const char* get_file_extension(const char* file_name)
{
 if(auto e = std::strrchr(file_name, '.'))
  return e + 1;

 return "";
}`

Comment: Do you realise you can usually compile code as C, and then link it into your C++ project using your linker?

Answer (score 5):

`strrchr` returning `NULL` is an inaccurate statement. `NULL` is a macro that expands to a null pointer constant. A null pointer constant is implicitly convertible to a null pointer of any pointer type. What `strrchr` returns is a null pointer constant that is converted to a `char*` null pointer.

`nullptr` is also a null pointer constant, with some special properties. But most of them are immaterial to us. When you compare it to a null pointer, of any type, the comparison will yield true if the pointer is a null pointer.

As a matter of fact, even `nullptr == NULL` is perfectly fine and will give you the sane result.